# How can I find the index of a value to compare to other elements

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method public static void removeDownTo (StackX stack, long n): It pops all values off the stack down to but not including the first element it sees that is equal to the second parameter. If none are equal, leave the stack empty.

I've tried to section off the problem by popping off the top half of the stack by reaching the n value. But the stack isn't sorted so it causes some problems.

```
public class StackX {
   private int maxSize;        // size of stack array
   private long[] stackArray;
   private int top;            // top of stack
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public StackX(int s)         // constructor
  {
  maxSize = s;             // set array size
  stackArray = new long[maxSize];  // create array
  top = -1;                // no items yet
  }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public void push(long j)    // put item on top of stack
{
  if (!isFull())
      stackArray[++top] = j;     // increment top, insert item
  else
     System.out.println("Can't insert, stack is full");
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public long pop()           // take item from top of stack
{
  if(!isEmpty())
     return stackArray[top--];  // access item, decrement top
  else
    System.out.print("Error: Stack is empty. Returning -1");   
   return -1;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
public long peek()          // peek at top of stack
{
   if (isEmpty()){
       System.out.print("stack is empty");
   }
  return stackArray[top];
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isEmpty()    // true if stack is empty
{
  return (top == -1);
}
//--------------------
public boolean isFull()     // true if stack is full
{
  return (top == maxSize-1);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public void removeDownTo (StackX stack, long n){ 
   for(int i = 0; stackArray[i] < n; i++){
       stack.pop();
   }
   for(int j = 0; stackArray[j] <= maxSize; j++){
       System.out.println(stackArray[j]);
   } 
  }
}
```

public class StackApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackX theStack = new StackX(10); // make new stack
    theStack.push(20); // push items onto stack
    theStack.push(40);
    theStack.push(60);
    theStack.push(80);
    while( !theStack.isEmpty()){ // until it's empty,
        theStack.removeDownTo(theStack, 40);
        long value = theStack.pop();
        System.out.print(value); // display it
        System.out.print(" ");
    } // end while
} // end main()
```

} // end class StackApp

I would expect to see 60 80 but instead I get 60 20.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are quite new to programming, your instructor has given you a task that is quite simple to solve. You should stick closely to its words. These words give you the main clues.

You are supposed to define this method:

```
public static void removeDownTo (StackX stack, long n)
```

Here, the word `static` is important. It means that the method should NOT go into the `StackX` class. (The instructions should mention this somewhere.) If your task had been to add the method to the `StackX` class, it would have looked like this:

```
public void removeDownTo (long n)
```

The difference between these two methods is that the latter has access to all the implementation details of the `StackX` class, which are the variables `maxSize`, `stackArray` and `top`.

But your task was different, your method should be `static`, and this means that it doesn't have access to these implementation details. All you can do is call the methods that are marked as `public`. There are 5 of them, they all start with a lowercase letter. Using only these 5 methods, you are supposed to solve this puzzle, as you wrote:

> It pops all values off the stack down to but not including the first element it sees that is equal to the second parameter. If none are equal, leave the stack empty.

By listing the 5 methods above, you can see that a stack allows only very few operations. Think of a large stack of books. You cannot just take one book from the middle, the only thing you can do is to look at the top of the stack. That's the nature of [a stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29).

You tried:

> I've tried to section off the problem by popping off the top half of the stack by reaching the n value. But the stack isn't sorted so it causes some problems.

This task is much simpler than you think. It is not about sorting at all. Follow the words in the instructions more closely. In the end, your `removeDownTo` method should be 5 lines long, from the beginning to the end. That means inside the braces, there are only 3 lines of code that you need to write.